# Find the magnitude of the two forces, which add up to the total forces of 50N?

Tags: vectors

i can't get it correct it wont equal to 50N. On my solution Y = 28.67 and X = 25. To sum that up it equals to 53

Here's the graph of it.

[image: force_diagram]

Comment: How did you get 25 by using a 35º angle? Don't you want $ \ 50 \ \cos 35º \ $ ?

Comment: yes i've tried that but the answer to that X + the answer of Y wont equal to 50N

Comment: Your value for $F_1$ is correct, but your value for $F_2$ is not.

Comment: Why do you expect the X and Y forces to add to 50N?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes my F2 is value is wrong, cant able figure it out

Comment: @JanBantolinay  Vector forces only add up like numbers if the forces point in the _same_ direction.  Because the two forces here are perpendicular, they sum like the legs of a right triangle.  You should look over how vectors are added in general (and how you get the magnitudes of vector components from a total $ \ F_T \ $ like you have here).

Comment: Observe that $F_2 = 50\cos(35^\circ)~\text{N}$.

Comment: No, no, no! The two values should NOT add to 50. That is not how vectors work. $50\cos(35^\circ)\approx40.96\cdots$

Comment: So the answer below is the real answer then. That's what i come up on my other solution which is f2 = 40.957.

Comment: Yes. $~$ As Mr. Pythagorus once said, or something like, "In a right angled triangle, the square of the Hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides."  $$\lvert \vec{F_T}\rvert^2=\lvert \vec{F_1}\rvert^2+\lvert \vec{F_2}\rvert^2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\vec{F_T} = \vec{F_1} + \vec{F_2} = - F_1 \vec{y} - F_2 \vec{x}
$$

$$
||\vec{F_T}||^2 = F_1^2 + F_2^2 = 50^2 ... (i)
$$

$$
\frac{F_1}{F_2} = \tan(35°) ...(ii) \to F_2^2(1+\tan^2(35°)) = 50^2
$$

$$
F_2 = 50 \cos(35°)\approx 40.957...
$$
$$
F_1 = 50 \sin (35°) \approx 28.678
$$